# Skylark - How to execute a jar from a repository rule

Tags: bazel

### Context

I am writing a repository rule that invokes another Bazel project. My current approach is to build the additional project as a deploy jar. I would like a user to be able to instantiate the rule like:

```
jar_path = some/relative/path
my_rule(name = "something", p_arg="m_arg", binary=jar_path)
```

and then given the jar_path and the arguments, I would like the repository rule to execute the following command in the shell:

```
java -jar $(SOME_JAR) $(ARGUMENTS_PROVIDED_BY_RULE)
```

### Problem

**First**, it's unclear how best to accomplish the deploy jar approach. So far, I have attempt two different approaches, with varying levels of success. For examples, I have skimmed through the scala_rules, the maven_rules, and the skylark cookbook.

**Second**, and more importantly, I am not sure whether the deploy jar is the best route to accomplishing my goals. Again, my interest is to invoke a target from an external Bazel project, that is currently hosted on github. (So feasibly, I could try to fetch the project using the http_archive rule).

Below, I describe the attempts I have made.

#### Approach 1

My first approach involved trying to execute the command using the `command` field in `ctx.action`. I tried various enumerations of

```
java -jar {computed_absolute_path_of_deploy_jar} {args_passed_from_instantiation}.
```

My biggest issue here was with determining the absolute path of the deploy jar. The file's root path, would contain some additional information. For example, it would like something like this.

```
/abs/olute/path[ something ]/rela/tive/path
```

As a side note, I'm not sure if this is a bug/nit, but the `File.root.path`, evaluated to None, despite `File.none` not being None.

[My first approach](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/cookbook.html#execute-a-binary) involved was to  was to try to use skylark [`ctx.binary`]

#### Approach 2

Next thing I tried was to mimic the input binary example [from the docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/cookbook.html#execute-an-input-binary). This was also unsuccessful. The issue was that the actual binary could not be found. Here is how I configured it.

First, I relaxed the repository rule into a regular skylark rule.

```
def _test_binary(ctx):
    ctx.action(
        ....
        arguments = [ctx.attr.p_arg],
        executable = ctx.executable.binary)

test_binary = rule(
    ...
    attrs = {
         "binary":attr.label(mandatory=True, cfg="host", allow_files=True, executable=True),
         ...

    }
```

Then, in my external project, I loaded the skylark rule into the WORKSPACE file. Finally, I called the macro from one of my BUILD files as follows:

```
load("@something_rule//:something_rule.bzl", "test_binary")

test_binary(name = "hello", p_arg = "hello", binary = "script.sh")
```

The script is a one line `java -jar something_deploy.jar -- -arg:$1`, and is in the same directory as the BUILD file.

Bazel complains that src/script.sh does not exist. I presume because it is looking for the file in `/private/var/tmp/-bazel_username/somehash/relative_path`. In response, I tried to pass the absolute path, which is not allowed.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the target you're trying to run from the other repo? What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up repository rules with build extensions ("normal" rules). A good rule of thumb is:

- Repository rules are for getting sources onto your system or symlinking them to a place Bazel can see them.
- Build extension are for everything else: compiling, copying files, running binaries, etc.

I don't actually think you need to use either, for this.  You say that the other project is on GitHub, so you can add the following to your WORKSPACE file:

```
http_archive(
    name = "other_project",
    ...
)
```

Then, in your BUILD file:

```
genrule(
    name = "run-a-jar",
    srcs = ["@other_project//some/relative:path"],
    cmd = "java -jar $(location @other_project//some/relative:path) -- arg1 arg2 > $@",
    outs = ["jar-output"],
)
```

You shouldn't need to use the `_deploy.jar` target, since you're not moving the jar out of its project (`_deploy.jar` is useful when you need to relocate it).

Other things from your question:

> I'm not sure if this is a bug/nit, but the File.root.path, evaluated to None,

Are you sure it didn't evaluate to `""`?  The path is relative to the execution root, so for sources, it will always be `""` (for outputs, it'll be `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin` or similar).

> Bazel complains that src/script.sh does not exist.

Passing `-s` to Bazel can really help debugging Skylark rules.  You can see exactly where it is looking.